# Is Razor Mediator compatible with Tridion Sites

Tags: web8.5, razormediator, razor

We are planning to upgrade Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1 with Razor Mediator to Tridion Sites 8.5.
Are there any breaking changes in 8.5 for Razor Mediator?
Will Razor Mediator be supported in Tridion 9?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Razor Mediator](http://appstore.sdl.com/web-content-management/app/razor-mediator/634/) is and community built extension and thus is not supported by SDL. However it is using the [Modular Templating Framework](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-6FF6827A-5B80-4C05-981B-9D2F11473BE5) and its [supported extension points](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-943F795D-22D9-40B0-9D0C-39981F4A5F51), so from that perspective, I would expect the Razor Mediator to remain to work. If not you probably want to contact its [owner](https://github.com/alex-klock/razor-mediator-4-tridion) and let him know.

As for the extension points being supported in Sites 9, since the Modular Templating Framework is not deprecated in Web 8.5, it will for sure still be there in Sites 9, so also there I would expect the Razor Mediator to still work.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's bit late to answer but we had to update IsSiteEditEnabled function for the razor mediator to work with SDL Web 8.5 for XPM functionality. If you are not using this function in your TBBs you should be fine.