# Razor template with tridion sites 9 without razor-mediator

Tags: razormediator, sites-9, razor

I am trying to preview razor template enabled page but I am getting error "**Unable to get template type with ID 8 for item tcm:xx-xxxx-xxxx.**" 
not sure it requires Razor mediator to be installed.

but is there any other way where configuration not required for Razor mediator on CME.

I am looking for an alternative solution for Razor mediator on Tridion sites 9, i do not want to install/configure Razor mediator on Tridion sites 9

> As there are legacy templates(razor) exist on cme, while running
>   template builder it always throws error mentioned above. for any template on cme.

please provide any suggestion on this.

Comment: why don't you want to install/configure razor mediator any specific reason

Comment: the only reason is i do not want additional customization on tridion cme installation, if there is no any other option then will have to think for it :(

Comment: There is no out-of-the-box replacement for the razor mediator.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately SDL officially only provides the Dreamweaver Mediator and the Razor Mediator or using Razor syntax for templates was never adopted by SDL.  Alexander Klock created the Razor Mediator by himself and gave it to the community to use.  I see he is no longer active in the Tridion community, but maybe someone else wants to take it up to port it to Sites 9?

Answer (score 1):

Razor mediator is a community extension and not supported by SDL.

For Sites 9, I do not recollect that Razor mediator would NOT be supported. You can refer the following answer from [Bart](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/18250/is-razor-mediator-compatible-with-tridion-sites) as well. From a technology perspective, there should be nothing limiting you from installing and configuring Razor Mediator with Sites 9.

If you choose NOT want to install and configure Razor Mediator (for whatever reasons), you will have to rewrite the template building blocks using a SDL supported templating framework.

In my opinion, you will be re-inventing the wheel using a new language with the above approach.